# MySQL Left Join (using MeekroDB)

Tags: mysql, meekro

This is really a MeekroDB exclusive issue, just trying to wrap my head around Left_Join.

I have 2 Tables: `comp_checklis`t and `comp_checklist_items`

I want to get all the rows from `comp_checklist` where the user Id matches and this worked fine:

`DB::query("SELECT * FROM comp_checklist WHERE user_id = %i", $user_id );`

Now I wand to get that same query ( all the rows from `comp_checklist` where the user Id matches ) and add any comp_checklist_items rows where `checklist_id` matches in both tables (`checklist_id` is the primary key in the `comp_checklist` table). I used below but just get `false`

`DB::query("SELECT * FROM comp_checklist WHERE user_id = %i LEFT JOIN comp_checklist_items on checklist_id = comp_checklist.checklist_id", $user_id );`

Answer (score 0):

JOIN should come before WHERE, and all columns should have the table name or you will get an error:

```
DB::query("SELECT * FROM comp_checklist 
           LEFT JOIN comp_checklist_items 
           ON comp_checklist_items.checklist_id = comp_checklist.checklist_id 
           WHERE comp_checklist.user_id = %i ", $user_id );
```

Comment: Got ya, that worked but in a different way I intended. Basically it returned Checklist A twice, once for each item instead of Checklist A once with another array with the items associated (nested) to it

Comment: @Packy If you want to get all rows with user_id = 3 for example, and there are two rows in comp_checklist_items for this checklist, you will get two results. If you want to get something else, post some sample data and a sample of the result set that you expect.